# Is it possible to change boot state for gpio in windows iot core

Tags: rpi.gpio, windows-iot

is it possible to change the initial boot state of the gpio pins using windows 10 iot core?

Per the documentation, by default 2-8 are pullup, and 9-27 are pulldown.

I'd like to change it so more are pullup.  Any ideas how to do so?

Comment: Why would you need to do that at boot? Shoulndt you be setting everying after boot??